# Why do I have to reference the ExceptionHandling.Logging dll in client code?

Tags: c#-4.0, enterprise-library

I've got a data access layer that is compiled into a dll. Within this layer, I'm using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll to log exceptions and then throw them back to the caller.

I've got a client application that references the data access layer dll but does not directly call into the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.dll. I get the following runtime exception in my client code when an exception occurs in the data access layer unless I add a reference to the Enterprise Library dll from my client application.

The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging.LoggingExceptionHandler, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' cannot be resolved. Please verify the spelling is correct or that the full type name is provided.

I don't understand why it's necessary for the client to reference the Enterprise Library dll even though it's not referencing it in code.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

It's all a question of the CLR locating and binding to your assemblies at runtime.

Since your Client directly calls your DAL.dll it needs a reference to the DAL.dll at compile time.  Similarily since your DAL.dll directly calls EL.Logging.dll  it needs a reference to the EL.Logging.dll at compile time.

However, since Client is not directly dependent on EL.Logging.dll it doesn't require a reference to compile.  That said, at runtime the CLR is going to have to locate and bind to all 3 assemblies: Client, DAL.dll, and EL.Logging.dll.

You are not required to add a reference to compile but by doing so with the Copy Local flag set to true you are deploying the EL.Logging.dll to the Client folder.  Now at runtime all the DLLs are locatable.

Other ways to achieve the same effect are:

- Register Enterprise Library in the GAC
- Create a post build action
- Manually perform an XCopy deployment of the DLLs you need
- Specify a `<codebase>` in configuration to locate the assemblies
- Use `<probing>` in configuration to probe subdirectories (probably not useful for you)

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to reference the Enterprise Library dll from your client application.
The problem is that the file is neither in the GAC, nor in your bin folder.  It gets copied when you add a reference to it from your Startup Project (client application) because the Copy Local property is set to True(default).

Only dll's that are directly references by your Startup Project are copied to the \bin folder.

Dll's that are references of references do NOT get copied.

The other way around this, if you don't want to directly reference the dll file, is to create a post-build script.